# Adding diagonal shading to map of United States

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, maps, visualization, plotly-python

I am making a map of the United States using plotly, and I have a couple states that fall into more than one category. For example, Oregon falls into more than one category, so I want Oregon to be striped with the colors corresponding to both categories.

My current data looks like the following after some cleaning (shown in code):

```
State  Category
===============
OR     3
OR     4
PA     1
SD     2
...
```

My map turns out well, but Oregon is displaying as only gray rather than a mix of the two category colors. How can I go about getting both colors to appear in a diagonal format?

```
# Assign numerical values to each category
category_values = {
    'Category 1': 1,
    'Category 2': 2,
    'Category 3': 3,
    'Category 4': 4
}

df['Cat_numeric'] = df['Categories'].map(category_values)

df = df.dropna(subset=['Cat_numeric'])

fig = go.Figure()

category_colors = {
    1: '#68a2cc',      
    2: '#dde729',      
    3: '#85b3a3',      
    4: '#ffb81d'      
}

# Define the colorscale for Oregon outside the loop
oregon_colorscale = [
    [0, '#85b3a3'],   # Start with the category color
    [0.5, 'gray'],    # Transition to gray at midpoint
    [1, '#ffb81d']    # End with the category color again
]

# Iterate through each state to create choropleth map traces
for state, value in zip(df['State'], df['Cat_numeric']):
    if state == 'OR':
      colorscale = oregon_colorscale
    elif value in category_colors:
        # Set custom color for each category if found in the dictionary
        colorscale = [[0, category_colors[value]], [1, category_colors[value]]]
    else:
        # Set a default color for any category not found in the dictionary
        colorscale = [[0, 'gray'], [1, 'gray']]

    fig.add_trace(go.Choropleth(
        locationmode='USA-states',
        locations=[state],
        z=[value],
        colorscale=colorscale,
        showscale=False,  # Hide the color bar
    ))
```

Comment: there are two ways i can think about doing this, and neither are easy: you can manually draw lines on an interactive map of oregon, and then extract and input those lines into a dataframe that you use as scatter-line traces on top of your current choropleth. or the more generalizable, but harder way: write a program that automatically draws straight lines between the left and bottom border of oregon up to the top or right border of oregon and draw those as traces on top of your choropleth